# Scraping an parsing jockeys data using Task.Run

Tags: c#, performance, async-await, mvvm, task-parallel-library

I started to have HUGE doubts regarding my code and I need some advice from more experienced programmers and architects.

On the button click, the application runs a method, that is running a `ScrapJockeys` with parameters:

`if (UpdateJockeysPl) await ScrapJockeys(JPlFrom, JPlTo + 1, "jockeysPl"); //1 - 1049`

Purpose of this is to scrap some data from web service and parse it with a model:

```
public class LoadedJockey
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Link { get; set; }
        public List<JockeyRaceDetails> AllRaces { get; set; }
    }
```

When the data is parsed, object is added to `ObeservableCollection<LoadedJockey>` and the collection is saved. Thanks to this, and based on the data the application can do computation of Jockey performace in the past.

And now more about the method and problems with the method:

I have a method, that is triggering a `for` loop, repeating between 20K - 150K times. Inside the loop I need to call a service method, that execution of the method takes a lot of time. Also I wanted to have ability of canellation of the loop and everyting what is going on inside of the loop/method.

Right now I have a method with list of tasks, and inside of the loop is trigerred a `Task.Run`. And inside of each task I am calling awaited service method. Also each task has assigned cancellation token, like [IN THE EXAMPE](https://github.com/przemyslawbak/Horse_Picker/blob/190f4549375c9e499c393dc2f3b734a0b802dd8a/Horse_Picker/ViewModels/MainViewModel.cs#L1657):

```
public async Task ScrapJockeys(int startIndex, int stopIndex, string dataType)
        {
            //init values and controls
            CommandStartedControlsSetup("UpdateDataCommand");
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
            int loopCounter = 0;
            ProgressBarTick("Looking for jockeys", loopCounter, stopIndex, startIndex);

            for (int i = startIndex; i < stopIndex; i++)
            {
                if (TaskCancellation == true)
                {
                    break;
                }

                int j = i;

                Task task = Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    LoadedJockey jockey = new LoadedJockey();

                    CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                    if (dataType == "jockeysPl") jockey = await _scrapServices.ScrapSingleJockeyPlAsync(j);
                    if (dataType == "jockeysCz") jockey = await _scrapServices.ScrapSingleJockeyCzAsync(j);

                    if (jockey.Name != null)
                    {
                        lock (((ICollection)Jockeys).SyncRoot)
                        {
                            //if objects are already in the List
                            if (Jockeys.Any(h => h.Name.ToLower() == jockey.Name.ToLower()))
                            {
                                LoadedJockey doubledJockey = Jockeys.Where(h => h.Name.ToLower() == jockey.Name.ToLower()).FirstOrDefault();
                                Jockeys.Remove(doubledJockey);
                                MergeJockeysData(doubledJockey, jockey);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Jockeys.Add(jockey);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    loopCounter++;

                    //saves all every 1000 records, just in case
                    if (loopCounter % 1000 == 0)
                    {
                        await _dataServices.SaveAllJockeysAsync(Jockeys.ToList());
                    }

                    ProgressBarTick("Looking for jockeys", loopCounter, stopIndex, startIndex);

                }, TokenSource.Token);

                tasks.Add(task);
            }

            try
            {
                await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                //
            }
            finally
            {
                await _dataServices.SaveAllJockeysAsync(Jockeys.ToList()); //saves everything to JSON file

                AllControlsEnabled = true;

                CommandCompletedControlsSetup();

                VisibilityCancellingMsg = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }
```

So my question is, is everything fine with my code? According to [THIS ARTICLE](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html):

> Many async newbies start off by trying to treat asynchronous tasks the
>   same as parallel (TPL) tasks, and this is a major misstep.

What should I use then?

And according to [THIS ARTICLE](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html):

> On a busy server, this kind of implementation can kill scalability.

So how am I supposed to do it?

Please be noted, that service interface method signature is `Task<LoadedJockey> ScrapSingleJockeyPlAsync(int index);`

And also i am not 100% sure that I am using `Task.Run` correctly within my service class. The methods inside are wrapping the code inside `await Task.Run(() =>`, like [IN THE EXAMPLE](https://github.com/przemyslawbak/Horse_Picker/blob/190f4549375c9e499c393dc2f3b734a0b802dd8a/Horse_Picker/DataServices/ScrapDataServices.cs#L566):

```
public async Task<LoadedJockey> ScrapSingleJockeyPlAsync(int index)
        {
            LoadedJockey jockey = new LoadedJockey();
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                int n;
                List<JockeyRaceDetails> allRaces = new List<JockeyRaceDetails>();

                for (int year = DateTime.Now.Year; year > 2013; year--)
                {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.Append("https://koniewyscigowe.pl/dzokej?d=");
                    sb.Append(index);
                    sb.Append("&sezon=");
                    sb.Append(year);
                    sb.Append("#wyniki_koni");

                    string link = sb.ToString();

                    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
                    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(link);

                    //gets the name of the jockey
                    if (jockey.Name == null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            HtmlNode singleNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/main/section[1]/div[1]/h3");
                            string racersName = singleNode.OuterHtml.ToString();
                            if (racersName.Contains("Jeździec") && racersName.Length > 65)
                            {
                                racersName = racersName.Split('>')[1].Split(new string[] { " - " }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Split('<')[0].Trim(' ');
                                if (racersName.Contains(" "))
                                {
                                    char letter = racersName[0];
                                    racersName = racersName.Split(' ')[1].Trim(' ');
                                    racersName = letter + ". " + racersName;
                                }

                                racersName = MakeTitleCase(racersName);

                                jockey.Name = racersName; //jockeys name
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                racersName = "";
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {

                        }
                    }

                    //scrap races
                    HtmlNode[] tableRow = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"wykaz_list\"]/tbody/tr").ToArray();
                    if (tableRow != null && tableRow.Length > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (var row in tableRow)
                        {
                            string stringTableRow = row.OuterHtml.ToString();

                            //all races
                            //if row not contains 'brak startow' and contains m (meters)
                            if (!stringTableRow.Contains("Brak danych") && (stringTableRow.Contains("&nbsp;m") || stringTableRow.Contains(" m")))
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    JockeyRaceDetails race = new JockeyRaceDetails();

                                    string raceDate = stringTableRow.Split('>')[3].Split('<')[0].Trim(' ');
                                    string raceDistance = stringTableRow.Split('>')[8].Split(' ')[0].Trim(' ');
                                    string horsesName = stringTableRow.Split('>')[10].Split('<')[0].Trim(' ');
                                    horsesName = MakeTitleCase(horsesName);
                                    string raceScore = stringTableRow.Split('>')[12].Split('<')[0].Trim(' ');
                                    string racePlace = raceScore.Split('/')[0].Trim(' ');
                                    string raceCompetitors = raceScore.Split('/')[1].Trim(' ');

                                    race = ParseJockeyRaceData(raceDate,
                                        raceDistance,
                                        horsesName,
                                        raceScore,
                                        racePlace,
                                        raceCompetitors);

                                    allRaces.Add(race);
                                }
                                catch (Exception e)
                                {

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                jockey.AllRaces = allRaces; //jockeys races between 2015-2019
                jockey.Link = "https://koniewyscigowe.pl/dzokej?d=" + index; //racers link

                if (jockey.AllRaces.Count == 0)
                {
                    jockey.Name = null;
                }

            });
            return jockey;
        }
```

As far as I understand from the articles, this is kind of anti-pattern. But I am confused a bit. Basing on [THIS SO REPLY](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56187088/11027921), it should be fine...? If not, how to replace it?

Comment: @dfhwze i saw your reply. With `j` I was passing proper `ID` to the service. It is based on similar case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33275940/11027921

Comment: @bakunet It seems my knowledge of C# is rusty. My answer is only valid for very old versions and will never see daylight again! :p

Comment: @dfhwze hehe, cool :) My biggest concern is about proper using of `Task.Run`. Mr **Stephen Cleary** is suggesting in his articles, that I am doing it wrong. But in his **SO** reply he said nothing about that. So I am confused now.

Answer (score 6):

> ```
>                 if (TaskCancellation == true)
>                 {
>                     break;
>                 }
> ```

> ```
>                     CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
> ```

Some comments explaining why two different cancellation methods are necessary would be useful.

---

> ```
>                     if (jockey.Name != null)
>                     {
>                         lock (((ICollection)Jockeys).SyncRoot)
>                         {
>                             //if objects are already in the List
>                             if (Jockeys.Any(h => h.Name.ToLower() == jockey.Name.ToLower()))
>                             {
>                                 LoadedJockey doubledJockey = Jockeys.Where(h => h.Name.ToLower() == jockey.Name.ToLower()).FirstOrDefault();
>                                 Jockeys.Remove(doubledJockey);
>                                 MergeJockeysData(doubledJockey, jockey);
>                             }
>                             else
>                             {
>                                 Jockeys.Add(jockey);
>                             }
>                         }
>                     }
> ```

There are at least four code smells here:

1. Using `Name` as a primary key. With real world data, what prevents two jockeys from having the same name?
2. Using an `ICollection` for something which clearly needs to be an `IDictionary`, given the way its contents are looked up.
3. ```
   if (collection.Any(predicate))
   {
       variable = collection.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
   ```

   searches twice, when one search suffices:

   ```
   variable = collection.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
   if (variable != null)
   {
   ```
4. If `MergeJockeysData` doesn't modify `Jockeys` then data would seem to be lost, but if it does modify then the data flow is being obfuscated.

---

> ```
>             try
>             {
>                 await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
>             }
>             catch (OperationCanceledException)
>             {
>                 //
>             }
>             finally
>             {
>                 await _dataServices.SaveAllJockeysAsync(Jockeys.ToList()); //saves everything to JSON file
> ```

`Task.WhenAll` is a blunt weapon. If there could be hundreds of tasks, you may find that you get better performance by placing a cap on the number of tasks which are executed simultaneously. This requires a lazy enumerator of tasks and a loop with `Task.WhenAny`.

If an `OperationCanceledException` is thrown, does it really make sense to save the partial results?

---

> ```
>                     HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
>                     HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(link);
> ```

This seems to me to be missing the point of `async`. It would make a lot more sense to me to first use `System.Net.WebClient.DownloadStringAsync` to do the IO asynchronously, and then load the string into HtmlAgilityPack for the CPU-bound part. In fact, unless memory consumption is an issue it probably makes sense to have a producer-consumer setup where multiple async tasks do IO and a single `Task.Run` does the parsing.

Comment: For more info about that `WhenAny` part, Microsoft describes it as Interleaving/Throttling: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/consuming-the-task-based-asynchronous-pattern

Comment: `TaskCancellation == true` breaks started loops; `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` cancels tasks; But I will double check, if I REALLY have to use the first one...; **Using Name as a primary key.** for data scrapping, if in returned object I will not get the name, the object is useless. And not each html document provides it; **Using an ICollection** why dictionary, if `Jockeys` is a collection? **3.** where did you find this? **4.** I will have to verify it.